# Connecting an AVD with an android device

Tags: android-emulator, wifi-direct

I want to test an android application using WiFi-Direct, and i want to ask if i can connect an virtual device created with VirtualBox with my real device android ?  thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt it would work. WIFI direct probably needs an actual interface, because it connects to a device directly without using a wireless router or other middleman. Since a virtual machine doesn't have a dedicated wifi device, it is limited to standard network communications.

Comment: But, i have installed Windroy, which have the WiFi-Direct option, then i want to test my app and connect it to a real device, because Windroy can create just one virtual device, and when i use the x86 images with VirtualBox, i can't found the WiFi-Direct option, and this is why i'am asking for the connection between an AVD and a real device, because i don't have another choice in this moment to test my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot connect an virtual device. Because Avd of pc is just simulator and doesnt have facility to such connections. You can check wifi in avd using internet connection of pc or VirtualBox but not to your real wifi.